# Evaluate a Surface Integral by Projection

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate the integral and something is a bit unclear to me

$\begin{equation}
\int\int f(x,y,z)dS\\
\end{equation}$

where $f(x,y,z)=x+z$ and $S=\{(x,y,z):x+y+z=1,x\geq0,y\geq0,z\geq0 \}$

I project the region $S$ onto the $xy$-plane and get

$\begin{equation}
\int\int (x+z)\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dz}{dy}\right)^2}\right)dxdy\\  
\end{equation}$

do I also substitute $z=1-x-y$ as $f(x,y,1-x-y)$ in the integrand?

Comment: $x+y+z \leq 1$ or $x+y+z = 1$?

Comment: @MathLover Its the portion of the plane $x+y+z=1$ that lies in the first quadrant. So, yes I think it must be $x+y+z\leq1$

Comment: No that is incorrect. If you are on the surface of the plane $x + y + z = 1$ regardless of which quadrant you are in. $x + y + z \leq 1$ will suggest volume, combined along with other given conditions $x, y, z \geq 0$.

Comment: @MathLover Oh I see. I will make the edit in the question

Comment: On your question, yes substitute $x+z$ with $1-y$ in your integral.